# How to run an .awk file without 'awk -f' command?

Tags: awk

I am new to awk script. I am trying to figure out how to run an awk file without awk -f command. I see people keep saying add "#!bin/awk -f" for the first line of an awk file. But this didn't for my awk. It still gives me "no file or directory" error.
I question is what does "#!bin/awk -f" really mean, and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `#!/bin/awk -f` not `#!bin/awk`. That will probably work, but theres no guaranty. If someone who has awk installed in a different location runs your script, it won't work. What you want is this: `#!/usr/bin/env awk -f`.

`#!` is what tells bash what to use to interpret your script. It should go at the very top of your file. It's called a Shebang. Right after that, you put the path to the interpreter.

`/usr/bin/env` finds where awk is located, and uses that script as the interpreter. So if they installed awk into somewhere else like `/usr/local/bin` then it'll find it. This probably won't matter for you, but it's a good habit to get into. It's more portable, and can be shared easier.

The `-f` says that awk is gonna read from a file. You could do `awk -f yourfilename.awk` in bash, but in the shebang, `-f` means the rest of the code will be the file it reads from.

I hope this helped. Feel free to ask me any questions if it doesn't work, or isn't clear enough.

**UPDATE**

If you get the error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘awk -f’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
```

then change the first line of your script to `#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f` (tested with GNU bash, version 4.4.23)

Comment: This produces the error:
    /usr/bin/env: ‘awk -f’: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
#!/bin/awk -f
```

(The first slash after the `#!` is important).

This tells unix what program it should use to 'run' the script with.

It is usually called the 'shebang'  which comes from hash + bang.

If you want to run your script like this  you need to make sure it is executable (`chmod +x <script>`).

Otherwise you can just run your script by typing the command `/bin/awk -f <script>`

Answer (score 0):

### The Shebang for Awk Explained

- `#!` is the start of a shebang line, which tells the shell which interpreter to use for the script.
- `/bin/awk` is the path to your awk executable. You may need to change this is your awk is installed elsewhere, or if you want to use a different version of awk.
- `-f` is a flag to awk to tell it to interpret the flag's argument as an awk script. In a shebang, it tells some awks to interpret the remainder of the script instead of a file.

### Your Shebang is (Probably) Broken

You are using `#!bin/awk -f` which is unlikely to work, unless you have awk installed as `$PWD/bin/awk`. You probably meant to use `#!/bin/awk` instead.

In some instances, passing a flag on the shebang line may not work with your shell or your awk. If you have the rest of the shebang line correct, you might try removing the `-f` flag and see if that works for you.